# Use AJAX in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am finding a tutorial for AJAX in magento 2. How can I use javascript to trigger a PHP function in Magento 2. In Wordpress, we have this:

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

I don't know if it is the same for Magento or in Magento world, we use different thing.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, your can install a module and assign it a URL route where you can send ajax call.

In this module controller execute() function you will put your php code.
at end of this function put echo "somthing" as response.

Here is an example plugin which you can install in magento2.
https://github.com/sanaullahAhmad/Magento2_cat_subcat_ajax_select_dropdowns

check this file for rout endpoint

```
Pulsestorm/HelloWorldMVVM/etc/frontend/routes.xml
```

it is "hello_mvvm"
If you wan to send ajax call to `Pulsestorm/HelloWorldMVVM/Controller/Hello/World.php`

you should put this in URL field of your ajax call

"http:example.com/index.php/hello_mvvm/hello/world"
This will lead to

```
public function execute(){
    //your code here
    echo "some response here";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a module that let’s you easily implement custom ajax requests in Magento 2. You might find the module useful or you can use the code to develop your own.

https://github.com/gaiterjones/Magento2_AjaxButton

Answer (score 1):

I have also written a small module for you, this is what is does:

Display a button click me on every page of the site. When clicking the button, a post ajax call is performed, the response is a simple json message

No gimmick in the module, if you need `get` rather than `post`, I am sure you'd be finding your way but if not, please let me know

the url is: https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/ajaxcall/src

UPDATE:

In this script below,

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Mbs_AjaxCall/js/clickme": {
                "ajaxUrl": "<?php echo $block->getUrl('mbsajaxdummy'); ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

the json

```
{
                "ajaxUrl": "<?php echo $block->getUrl('mbsajaxdummy'); ?>"
            }
```

is the config for the javascript file. Magento parsing picks up this json and makes it available to the clickme.js javascript file

hence, the javascript file:

```
define([
    "jquery"
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function(config, element) {
        console.log('config', config); // this will show you what is in the console
```

Comment: Where do you define the config.ajaxUrl in clickme.js

Comment: @coinhndp I have updated my answer

Comment: I added an button to checkout page and the checkout page is rendered by onepage.pthml and OnePage block. It's the system block (Checkout module), not my block. So how can I pass the getUrl to the JS file